# how to move the eclipse development platforms into one on ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

i have eclipse

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Eclipse for PHP Developers

Pulsar for Mobile Java Developers

but how can i merge them and have a single interface just by changing perspective rather as if i have installed them from the update site as a plug-in can i just move all the files from each of them and put them in the plugins folder that is found in

```
a@a $ ~/.eclipse/org .../plugins
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to start from a clean installation and install components from the UI of this install. You can for example install first

Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

and then install the 2 other ones using the Help -> Install new Software menu.

The main goal of this solution is about dependencies. The install software action (using P2 internally) will manage dependencies for you. The copy solution you mentioned should result in dependencies not resolved and difficult to identify.

Comment: as you said i tried to do " .. and then install the 2 other ones using the Help -> Install new Software menu. ..." but eclipse will not detect the other frameworks e.g. Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers  folder or zip as a repository @Manuel Selva

Comment: you should not use your local install as installation software repository but look on eclipse web site to find the update site of the features you need (CDT,PHP,Pulsar)

Comment: Or choose the default repository (called Galileo or Ganymede) or something like that

Comment: the files found on the default repository are the same as the individual frameworks why do i need the update site then? actually that is my q? if you get me